# ReadOnly rows in DataGridView

Tags: winforms

I have a binded DataGridView where depending on some BoundItem property value that line will be read only. What is the best way to implement this?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try The event CellBeginEdit

```
Private Sub Dgv_CellBeginEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles Dgv.CellBeginEdit
  If YourCondition(BoundItem.Property) then e.cancel = true
End Sub
```

This makes the cell readOnly depending on your condition.

Comment: I also use this approach. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

in the rowenter event, set the readonly property of the row accordingly

```
private sub MyView_RowEnter(...) handles MyView.RowEnter
    MyView.Rows(e.Rowindex).ReadOnly = (condition)
end sub
```

Comment: I thought that  I should do this on some binding event